# What is the actual use of self in init in python?

Tags: python

```py
class Time:
    def __init__(self, hours, minutes):
        self.hours = hours      # why do i need to write these steps?
        self.minutes = minutes
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano got it :D

Answer (score 4):

`self` represents the instance of the class.

Therefore, using `self.hours` and `self.minutes` you can set the instance attributes of the object of class `Time`.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have:

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, arg1):
      self.argument1 = arg1
   def print_1(self):
      print(self.argument1)
```

When you create a `class` like this, the `self` points to an instance.

```
instance1 = MyClass("hello")
instance2 = MyClass("bye")
```

Doing `print(instance1.print_1()` will print `"hello"`, and `print(instance2.print_1()` will print `"bye"`

So, `self` is a way to differentiate and manage multiple instances of the same class. And **different instances** will have its own set of **different variables**.

Answer (score -1):

**init** is the instance of your class. When a class is called this method will be invoked first with the relevant arguments needs to be passed. self.minutes = minutes you are storing the minutes parameter to a new class variable reference called self.minutes. By convention we use self as the first parameter.